# DataGrid problems with vertical scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I have a problem with vertical scrollbar in my `DataGrid`. When there is only one record in `DataGrid` scrollbar doesn't show even if this record takes more space than `DataGrid` have.
Here is example:
[image]

But when I have more than one item in `DataGrid` scrollbar works fine:
[image]

So my question: Is there any way to fix such behavior of `DataGrid`'s
 `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: is der any columns property Frozen set to True.

Comment: @Ravi Kanth no there is no frozen columns